# HTTP Error 404: Not Found python urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

My code is this:

```
import urllib.request
import re
http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Paris/forcasts/latest

city = input('Please enter a place: ')
url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'+city+'forcasts/latest'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data1 = data.decode('utf-8')
```

I'm having trouble with the url this is my output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/alext/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Weather forecast.py", line 9, in 
>       data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 564, in error
>       result = self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
>       return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib          \request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>       urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I have checked the url and it is definitely correct. I have seen others with problems like this but am still unsure as to the solution.

Comment: Ahem try going to `http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Paris/forcasts/latest` Maybe you should have triple-checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a / after the city and a e in forecast. It should be

```
url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'+city+'/forecasts/latest'
```

Comment: I also missed that you need a e in forecasts, so it is `url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'+city+'/forecasts/latest'`